# Python: check if a key exists in a nested dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to check if a certain key exists in a nested dict.

e.g:

```py
x = [{
    '11': { 
        0: [
               {
                'bb_id': '122',
                'cc_id': '4343'
               }
           ],           
        
        1: [
               {
                'bb_id': '4334',
                'cc_id': '3443'
               },
               {
                'bb_id': '5345',
                'cc_id': '257'
               }
           ]
    }
}]
```

I need to check if the key `'11'` exists in `x`, and further if the key `0` exists in the value of the key `'11'`.

I've tried doing:

```py
print(any(0 in d for d in x if '11' in d))
```

Comment: `x` is not a dict, it's a list - and lists don't have keys.

Comment: try: `print(any(0 in d['11'] for d in x if '11' in d))`?

Comment: ``any(v.get('11', {}).get(0) for v in x)`` ?

Comment: thenk you shushanth!

Answer (score 3):

It seems this would achieve what you are trying to do:

```py
any(['11' in d.keys() and 0 in d['11'].keys() for d in x])
```

**Explanation:**

- Iterate over each dictionary in the list named `x`;
- Search each dictionary for a key of `'11'`, and search its value (which is expected to be a dictionary too) for a key of `0`;
- If both conditions are met, return `True`; else, return `False`.

---

In the question's comments, Sushanth has provided an even shorter and possibly more Pythonic way, using a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and the dictionary's `get()` method with an empty dictionary as a fallback value:

```py
any(d.get('11', {}).get(0) for d in x)
```

Comment: You dont have to use a print in a list comprehension since it will print the TRUE but return a [None].

Comment: Plus your result ```doesnt return a FALSE``` if '11' is not in the dict. So your solution is incorrect. It only returns a blank list [ ].

Comment: Printing in a list comprehension is not a recommended practice. Secondly, it doesnt meet the condition where if '11' is not a key. That just fails and returns nothing. as OP mentioned, he needs True if both conditions are met but its implicit that a False is returned if any of them isnt.

Comment: Noted, thanks for feedback. Improved the solution so that it meets the additional criteria.

Answer (score 1):

> What you have here is a list of dicts with values as a dict of lists of dicts.

Try this one-liner list comprehension. `x` here is a list of dicts (in this case with a single dict). The code below returns True for every dict that is in `x` if `'11' exists in its key` AND if `0 exists in the key of value of '11'`. Only if both conditions are met, you get a `TRUE` else `FALSE` -

1. Iterate over items of x
2. Iterate over the dicts inside items of x
3. Check if the items in x have a key = '11' AND if items in dicts inside items of x have key = 0
4. If both conditions are met, return `True` else `False`

```
#Items to detect
a = '11'
b = 0

#Iterate of the nested dictionaries and check conditions
result = [(k==a and b in v.keys()) for i in x for k,v in i.items()]
print(result)
```

```
[True]
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with another way to do it.

```py
(d.get('key1') or {}).get('key2')
```

Our example:

```
(x[0].get('11') or {}).get(0)
```

**Explanation of Steps:**

`x[0]` = Gets dictionary

`(x[0].get('11') or {})` = Tries and gets key `'11'` key from dictionary `x`; if the key doesn't exist, then just set a blank dictionary `{}`.

`(x[0].get('11') or {}).get(0)` = Remember `.get()` on a dictionary will return None if the `0` doesn't exist rather than throw an error.

```
get(key[, default])

Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. 
If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.
```

[See Python docs here for .get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20get#dict.get)

Answer (score 0):

A raw way to do that could just be an if condition:

```py
if '11' in x[0]:
    print("11 in x")

if 0 in x[0]['11']:
    print("0 in 11")
```

You could also use a for loop:

```py
for d in x:
    if '11' in d:
        print("11 in d")
        if any(d['11']) and 0 in d['11']:
            print("0 in 11")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
has_key = lambda key, _dict: re.search("{%s" % str(key),   str(_dict).replace(" ", ""))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you edit your answer to provide some explanation of your code? Take a look at [Akshay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63327547/3025856) or [Pitamer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63327550/3025856) as good references for how to contribute answers.