# Return null if the field doesn't exist

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get all the data I need from elasticsearch API using python.

However, the data in each objects are different. WHat I mean is:

for instance:

```
hits: [
 "_source": {
   "info": {
      "id": 1234,
      "name": "xyz apt"
      "address": "adsfv"
}},
"_source": {
   "info": {
      "id": 3579,
      "name": "abc apt"
}}, ...
```

as seen, in the second one,  "address" data doesn't exist so when I go through a for loop to get each data I get an error.

```
for i in hits: 
   address.append(i['_source']['info']['address'])
```

So how to null such values when data doesn't exist?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: check if a key exists in a nested dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63327372/python-check-if-a-key-exists-in-a-nested-dict)

Comment: I recommend you take a look at Pydantic (https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic) to define Models for your data with default values, then for each object coming out of ES just cast it into the model and you will have a "full" set of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you address a key that may or may not exist, you can use`.get`:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1}
>>> d['b']
KeyError
>>> str(d.get('b'))
'None'
```

`.get` also accepts a default value:

```
>>> d.get('b', 'something that will be returned if the key is not present')
'something that will be returned if the key is not present'
```